# Flutter - How to use data retrieved from FireStore without using SteamBuilder?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to retrieve the data from the `Firestore`. I did it successfully with the help of `StreamBuilder` widget. What I want is to pass the data I get from the `firestore` to another screen.

I don't want to print a `ListView` with the `StreamBuilder`, just want to get the data and pass to the next screen I am calling from `Navigator.push(...`

So this is my `get_news()` method where I have implemented to get the data:

```
  // get the news
  Stream<List<News>> getNews() {
    return _db.collection("news").snapshots().map(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.documents
              .map((doc) => News.fromMap(doc.data, doc.documentID))
              .toList(),
        ) ;
  }
```

And this is my `News` model.

```
class News {
  final String headline;
  final String description;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String timeNews;
  final String timeDate;
  final String priority;
  String id;


  News({this.headline,this.description, this.imageUrl, this.timeNews, this.timeDate, this.priority, this.id});

  News.fromMap(Map<String,dynamic> data, String id):
    headline=data['headline'], 
    description=data['description'], 
    imageUrl=data['imageUrl'],
    timeNews=data['timeNews'],
    timeDate=data['timeDate'],
    priority=data['priority'],
    id=data['id'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap(){
    return {
      "headline" : headline,
      "description": description,
      "imageUrl": imageUrl,
      "timeNews": timeNews,
      "timeDate": timeDate,
      "priority": priority,
      "id": id,
    };
  }
}
```

This is how I pass it in normal circumstances through `StreamBuilder` - **Which I don't want to do now**

```
Expanded(
              child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: FireStoreServiceApi().getNews(),
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<News>> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError || !snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text("Invalid");
              } else {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    News news = snapshot.data[index]; // this is I want to get
                    return Text("Working");
                  },
                );
              }
            },
          )),
```

So without **using StreamBuilder**, how can I call `FireStoreServiceApi().getNews()` and get the `news` object?

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use a `changeNotifier`.  getNews instead of returning a Stream, will update a list and called notifyListeners. Your build method will listen to this via [ChangeNotifierProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProvider-class.html).

[This](https://medium.com/@aruny3/how-to-use-changenotifier-in-flutter-440371617b8c) should provide a good starting point to implement via changeNotifier.

Comment: I am new to flutter and this approach seems hard to implement. can you provide an example with reference to my scenario?